# update plot in while loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

i got this code:

```
 while cap.isOpened():

    pose = results.pose_landmarks.landmark
    pose_row_x = list(np.array([[landmark.x] for landmark in pose]).flatten())
    pose_row_y = list(np.array([[landmark.y] for landmark in pose]).flatten())
    pose_row_z = list(np.array([[landmark.z] for landmark in pose]).flatten())

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=[pose_row_x, pose_row_y, pose_row_z ]).T
    df.columns = ["x", "y", "z"]
  


    plt.scatter(df['x'],df['y'])
    plt.plot()
```

I would like to print the new added values in "real Time" in the same plot.
For every loop i got a new plot.

Is there any way to update the plot in every loop iteration ?

EDIT: PLOT:
[image]
I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a single [Axes object](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html) for all of your plots. Something like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

while cap.isOpened():

    # generate data here

    ax.scatter(df['x'], df['y'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The Plot i got is shown in the original post. I would like to see something lik an animation of the data. Is there any way to get this ? :)

Comment: Yeah I believe you can call `ax.clear()` right before `ax.scatter()` each iteration. That should do it.